# Why isn't the shell reading from Bash startup files?

Tags: terminal, bashrc, .bash-profile, .profile

I'm just trying to do the simple task of adding my [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) directory to the PATH variable so that I can use the `mysql`, etc. commands in my terminal on my Mac OS X 10.6.6 (Snow Leopard). After altering the `.profile`, `.bash_profile`, and even creating a `.bashrc`, and making sure that my path has been inputted correctly, every time I try running the `mysql` command, or hitting

```
echo $PATH
```

gives me the same exact results:

```
/Users/GabbAHH/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@rails3tutorial/bin:/Users/GabbAHH/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p136@global/bin:/Users/GabbAHH/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/bin:/Users/GabbAHH/.rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
```

As you can see, no MySQL. Later, I realize that this isn't really the problem since I removed all three of those files from my `/Users/GabbAHH/` user directory, and I still get the same result!

Right now, the script inside my startup files look like this:

```
export PATH=/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH

export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH"
```

Was there something I've done that made my Terminal bypass these startup files? Is it just reading from the `/etc/profile` folder?

Does that give the same result? Regardless, I've interchanged them.

Also, how do I tell if I'm using an interactive or non-interactive shell, and a log-in/non log-in shell? I seem to be able to create folders, etc. without a prompt to input my password, although I remember prior I had to `sudo` a lot of commands when installing [gems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RubyGems) for Ruby, etc. Also, I did need to input my password when turning MySQL on/off.

Comment: does it work outside the startup script?

Comment: @writ Instead of yelling *Thank you very much* a better option would be to *accept* his answer by clicking on the green checkmark beside his answer, to indicate that he's solution helped you solve your problem ;)

Answer (score 2):

Just put:

```
echo HELLO, I AM HERE
```

in your startup script and login as per normal.

If you find that the string is *not* printing out then, yes, you're bypassing that script.

Beyond that, you should tell us *which* script you're putting it in since `bash` has some ... rather wondrous ... rules for deciding which scripts get run :-) You can get the details from the `INVOCATION` section of `man bash`. My particular version goes on for about 50 lines (and that's with a 150-column `xterm`) so I won't bore you by posting it here.

Suffice to say it's complicated.

For example, you may be being bitten by the fact that `bash` will only execute the *first* of `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, and `~/.profile` that exists and is readable. It may be a non-interactive shell where the rules are different. You may be running the shell with `--noprofile` or `--norc` or `--rcfile=whatever` or `--posix`.

The possibilities, while not endless, are damnably annoying.

Comment: Thank you for your response! 
When I open terminal (no log-in) I do get "HELLO, I AM HERE" printed when I enter "echo HELLO, I AM HERE". So, does this mean that the script to use the startup files is not being bypassed? Again, I don't think my Terminal is reading those 3 aforementioned startup files at all, since I got the same result in echo $PATH when I removed them completely from my home user holder. I'm not sure what you mean by the invocation section. I entered "man bash" which first printed out rows of blank lines, and then some descriptions that does not include invocation

Comment: If you put that `echo` in the startup file and the terminal printed it out when it started, then it _is_ being processed. In the script where you add mysql to the path, precede that with `echo XYZZY` and put `echo $PATH` after it.

Comment: Thank you paxdiablo for your quick response. I didn't even do what you last told me to, but I simply one by one removed the HELLO, I AM HERE script from my startup script files and narrowed it down to the .bash_profile that is being read from. The good news is, after removing them all completely, my MySQL commands work now! But what's troublesome is that I have no idea why it works now since I have the same exact script as before. I haven't even restarted my computer. I've just entered the echo XYZZY and echo $PATH into .bash_profile and I get

Comment: XYZZY
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/usr/X11/bin
Typing in echo $PATH still elicits the same thing as before. This means I still don't see the MySQL directory listed anywhere! This is my .bash_profile currently:    echo XYZZY
echo $PATH

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/mysql/bin:$PATH

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"  # This loads RVM into a shell session.export          What's even more disturbing is that I can't seem to reproduce the same results as removing your two lines, i got the same....

Comment: bash: command not found error again when typing a MySQL command, but later, when I readd, resave, remove, resave, it works all over again! It seems to have a mind of it's own, at the expense of my mind!

Answer (score 2):

My issue was the existence of a .bash_profile, so I made my changes by modifying there. All it was doing before was setting up my JAVA_HOME and a GROOVY_HOME...so I added my changes to the end of that file and now all is working great.

Thanks!